# Using ModelBuilder to iterate through LAS files using custom LASToolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, lidar, las, lastools

I'm trying to use ModelBuilder to iterate through a folder containing 25 usgs .las files and run 4 custom geoprocessing tools from the LAStools toolbox available on github.  I am able to successfully run each tool individually outside of ModelBuilder.  However, when I attempt to put the tools into a ModelBuilder workflow, the ModelBuilder says 'completed' without executing any of the tools.

Below is a screenshot for the workflow with one of the tools which is where I'm starting for now.  I included the tools parameter dialog box which I am leaving default (I used the same parameters when running on its own successfully).

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I've tried to specify an output name for each tool and still did not execute.  I need to use this tools output as input for the next tool and so on.

FYI, first time using iteration tool in ModelBuilder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lidar+modelbuilder?sort=newest&pageSize=50 to see if anything helps in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this model, and it run for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same setup as above.  This seems to have somthing to do whith the iterator not reading my .las files correctly.  I am getting the error below when trying to validating the model:                                            """ERROR 000732: input file: Dataset C:\CPRGISLocal\Projects\Lidar\USGS\Test\File.las does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (lasground)"""        Which is strange because if I drag them individually into the model without the iterator it's running on the files fine.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ZachS, I just built and run the model again and it worked. Sometimes Arcmap does not work properly when the path to the files is too long. What I always do is to keep my files in a folder with the shortest path possible, something like G:\input_files\ *.las. Regarding to the error, double click on the green oval (File.las) before you run the model to make sure the box under the File.las has the right path of the files C:\CPRGISLocal\Projects\Lidar\USGS\Test\File.las , if you keep trying the same path. FYI I just added more screenshots for the elements of my model to illustrate that.

Comment: @ZachS did you ever find a solution to you model builder issue?